# Confusion about the vanishing of a sum

Tags: functions, summation, proof-writing, solution-verification

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_j - x_{j-1})(\sup_{[x_{j-1},x_{j}]} f(x) -\inf_{[x_{j-1},x_{j}]} f(x) )=0$$

In the sum above, it originates from proving that $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$, where $f: [a,b] \mapsto R$ is bounded.

This can be done by claiming that $ \forall j $ in this sum, $ \sup_{[x_{j-1},x_{j}]} f(x) -\inf_{[x_{j-1},x_{j}]} f(x) = 0$ since each term in the sum is positive.

But I'm confused about something, what if different pairs in the sum are vanishing together rather than $\sup_{[x_{j-1},x_{j}]} f(x) $ and $\inf_{[x_{j-1},x_{j}]} f(x)$?

What I mean is, suppose we have a sum: $a+b+c+... = 0$ where $a,b,c,..$ are all positive, then for sure $a=b=c=...=0$

But what if I break each term into pairs, let's say $a=a_1-a_2$ and $b=b_1-b_2$ and so on..

The sum becomes: $a_1-a_2+b_1-b_2+... = 0$

What prevents me from saying that instead of $a_1-a_2$ being zero, that I have $a_1-b_2$ equaling zero? Given of course that is the sum that I begin with, not knowing that $a=b=c=...=0$

Comment: You don't know that $a_1-a_2\ge0$, $b_1-b_2\ge0$, etc.

Comment: I know that, but still, what prevents me from making the claim in the last paragraph?

Comment: $-1+1=0$ even though $-1\ne0$.